# Java Relection Instance checking for different classes

Tags: java, reflection

I have method which takes in Class references as arguments something like below:

```
getConfigModule(Class klass) {
    //logic to check the class types
}
```

We are calling this method from other classes like below:

```
    getConfigModule(ClassA.class);
    getConfigModule(ClassB.class);
    getConfigModule(ClassC.class);
```

I need to write some logic in the method to check whether "klass" is of a particular class type or not. For example to check "klass" is of type ClassA and ClassB.

Comment: Seems like the trivial and brute force approach here is to use instanceof....

Comment: Do these classes share a common (and discriminating) superclass? If so, just make the parameter type `Class<? extends ThatClass>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner : might be an issue when handling multiple interface implmenentations

Comment: does this help `ClassA.class == klass`?

Comment: using ClassA.class == klass helps since i dont have any superclass or superinterface types for these classes

Comment: Please make clear what you want `getConfigModule` probably has a result, correct. Is it of the same type as the class you put in? Do you have a list of Objects and you return the one that matches the given class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @@RannLifshitz mentioned, the most straightforward way is to you `if-then-else if` or `switch` approach. If you know there are only 3 options and could bet nothing would be added then it's ok.

For long-term project the enum way could be used.

```
public enum PossibleClasses {
    CLASS_A(ClassA.class), CLASS_B(ClassB.class);
    Class klass;

    PossibleClasses(Class klass) {
        this.klass = klass;
    }

    static PossibleClasses fromClass(Class desiredClass) {
        for (PossibleClasses current:PossibleClasses.values()) {
            if (current.klass == desiredClass) {
                return current;
            }
        }
        // here you could implement logic regarding class inheritance or something else.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uknown class:"+desiredClass);
    }
}
```

Then you compare with enum values instead of `Class`.

```
if (PossibleClasses.fromClass(klass) == CLASS_A) {
  //do something
}
```

This will help when you will modify code. For example, if someone calls method with completely new class, he would get infromative exception. Also you could use some standard features for enums such as `EnumSet` to wite clear code like

```
// would be a field
private EnumSet<PossibleClasses> commonOption =  EnumSet.of(CLASS_A, CLASS_B);

// somewhere inside code
if (commonOption.contains(PossibleClasses.fromClass(klass))) { 
   // instructions which are common for both classes
}
```

---

Again, playing with enums is good idea for long-term project. For startup or education/investigation project most probably you can't get benefits from those additional lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(klass) or klass.isAssignableFrom(Foo.class)` if by same type you mean the class `Foo` is a superclass or superinterface of `klass` or the other way around.

If you want strict equality just use `equals` method.